# MONACAバックエンドのバックアップについて

Tags: monaca

MONACAバックエンドについて教えてください。

MONACAバックエンド、コレクションに登録したデータについては
どのようにバックアップを取ることができるのでしょうか。

ソースについてはWebDAVを利用してバックアップが取れることを確認したのですが
MONACAバックエンド、コレクションについて、エクスポートなどの方法があれば
教えていただけませんでしょうか?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

自己解決しましたのでご報告いたします。

まず、バックエンドのデータについては、どのプランにおいても
自動ソースバックアップの対象にはなりません。

バックエンドの内容、コレクションの内容のエクスポートについては
MonacaバックエンドマネジメントAPIのCollectionItem.listを使用して
スクリプトをコーディングし、取得するという方法になるようです。
（つまりMonacaバックエンドマネジメントAPIが使えるプランの契約が必要です。）

又はMONACAと連携しているNifty mobile backendを利用すれば
エクスポート機能を利用してより簡単にデータ取得ができるとの事でした。

以上、ご参考になればと思い、投稿させていただきます。